# Generate a random number out one after another can be dragged and Dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I need help to input a random number after the top number in the stack of cards has been pulled and dropped correctly. Here's my JavaScript code to create random number and I have 10 slots, so everytime I pulled to the correct slot the random number will show out:

```
//Create the pile of shuffled cards
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
numbers.sort(function () {
    return Math.random() - .5
});

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

  $('<div>' + numbers[i] + '</div>')
    .data('number', numbers[i])
    .attr('id', 'card' + numbers[i])
    .appendTo('#cardPile')
    .draggable({
        containment: '#content',
        stack: '#cardPile div',
        cursor: 'move',
        revert: true
    });
}

//event to drag and check if it's correct or wrong place

function handleCardDrop(event, ui) {
   var slotNumber = $(this).data('number');
   var cardNumber = ui.draggable.data('number');

  /* If the card was dropped to the correct slot,
     change the card colour, position it directly
     on top of the slot, and prevent it being dragged
     again */

 if (slotNumber == cardNumber) {
    ui.draggable.addClass('correct');
    ui.draggable.draggable('disable');
    $(this).droppable('disable');
    ui.draggable.position({
            of: $(this),
            my: 'left top',
            at: 'left top'
        });
    ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
 }                           
 }
```

Comment: Can you refine your question for clarity?  I can't tell which number you want access to, the card which has just been dropped, or the next card in the "deck."  And I'm not sure what you want to do with the number, once you have it.

Comment: @asciimo :For instance, I have 10 numbers in the array.
I generate each of the number randomly and placed in the each <div> that I have created when they generate out 

After the number is successfully drop into the slot, then I want the 
empty slot to generate random number out repeatedly 

In general, I want to do a game to pull and drop the cards to the correct slot repeatedly.

Comment: @asciimo Overall, I will be doing a pull and drop card game , where user repeatedly pull and drag as many cards within a specific timing, into the correct slot. Each correct slot will earn them 10 points.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  What do you wish to do with the random number generated on successful drop?

Comment: @Asciimo I would like it to be repeatedly draggerable. Logically the same. Dropped correctly gets the point. However if dropped into the wrong slot, the number will fly back to it's original place or it can be deduction of point, depending which one is more easier to code:)

Comment: @asciimo I'm sorry to disturb you. But are you able to help me?
This is where I got my tutorials btw. http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/

Is it possible to guide me to accomplished my game ?

Answer (score 0):

If I have interpreted your requirements correctly, you simply need to make your "deck" of cards really big, and stack all the divs on top of each other with absolute positioning.

```
.new-card {
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Then, as you successfully drag and drop each card, the next will be revealed naturally.  If you truly want an infinite deck then you can regenerate the stack whenever the container DIV has no more DIV.new-card children.

I have created a JSFiddle to illustrate my interpretation of your issue and my recommendation. At the very least, I hope that this example will be useful for discussing the issue further.

http://jsfiddle.net/asciimo/5qAPe/1/

Comment: Thank For Doing the Requirements that I wanted last time. But the idea had been slightly modified.
I would like stack of 4x7 pull and drop game. Every One pull is 10 points. after the user pulled finished the cards. the new card will reset and continue for them to pulled.
The cards was to be replace with meaningful images actually.
If u are able to teach me how to arrange it with images that would be great. :D

Comment: For the 4x7, it sounds like you should use 28 independent decks.  I would maintain the numbering strategy, but create a new data structure that maps those numbers (used as keys) to images. e.g. { 1 : 'heart.png', 2: 'diamond.png', 3: 'wolf.png', ... }  Then, rather than displaying the number in the card DIV, display the associated image in an IMG tag.